# What kind of artificial intelligence is this? A decentralized swarm intelligence where the input and output is split among the agents

Tags: reinforcement-learning, swarm-intelligence

I have an AI design for deciding the length of green and red lamps of the traffic. In my design, every crossroads has its own agent. This agent has input the amount of vehicle in each road in a single junction. AI then decide how long is the red lamp and the green lamp in each junction. The fitness function is the average commute time in the city. Each agent may communicate with each other, and give reward or punishment to other AI. What AI algorithm works like this?